# Bar Chart : Join on a label

Tags: bar-chart, grafana

I just started using grafana, I don't have a lot of knowledge about it, but I can't find a topic about what I'm trying to do. I don't even know if it's possible in fact.

I have the following gauge metrics on prometheus

`switch_free_ports{switch="switch_one"} 8.0`
`switch_free_ports{switch="switch_two"} 222.0`
`switch_used_ports{switch="switch_one"} 88.0`
`switch_used_ports{switch="switch_two"} 102.0`

My goal would be to create a Bar Chart that looks like the following image

[Bar Chart goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0xJT.png)

But the first "duo" of bar would be "switch_one" and the second "switch_two"
And for each of them, the green bar would represent the "free port" and the yellow bar the "used ports"

So far I haven't been able to find a way to group by switch.

I have 2 query for both metrics:
`laas_switch_free_ports laas_switch_used_ports`

Then I tried different method, using the different "Transforms" tools; Reduce, Outer Join, Group By.
Label to Field.

I can't manage to make the GroupBy working on "switch", I can only group on a specific switch like "switch_one"

First of all : Is what I want to do possible ?

If yes: Do you have any tips that can help me ?
If no: Is there an alternative that would work ? By changing my prometheus data for exemple ?

I've also saw on different topics/videos that people are creating this bar chart from a table.
I tried to transform my metrics into a table, but I didn't manage to make it work as well

Thanks